# Differentiate $v(x,y)= \int_{(a,b)}^{(x,y)}[-u_y(x,y) dx + u_x(x,y) dy]$ with respect to $y$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

> Let $u(x,y)$ be some **harmonic** function with continuous partials. Let $v(x,y)= \int_{(a,b)}^{(x,y)}[-u_s(s,t) ds + u_s(s,t) dt]$. Find $v_y$ at some point $(x_0,y_0)$.

I don't think anything like Leibniz' rule works here, so I think all we are left with is using the definition of the partial derivative. 
$v_y(x_0,y_0)= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}[v(x_0,y_0+h)-v(x_0,y_0)] = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}[\int_{(x_0,y_0)}^{(x_0,y_0+h)} -u_ydx+u_x dy]= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} [\int_{(x_0,y_0)}^{(x_0,y_0+h)} u_x(x_0,y_0+th) h \ dt] = \lim_{h \to 0}  [\int_{(x_0,y_0)}^{(x_0,y_0+h)} u_x(x_0,y_0+th) h \ dt] = u_x(x_0,y_0). $

I used path-independence of $v$ ( by Greene's theorem, noting partials are $C^1$) in the 2nd line, choosing the straight line path from $y_0$ to $y_0 +h$.

I am not at all sure about this argument, so if anyone could tell me where I've gone wrong that would be great!

Comment: As it stands, the integral makes no sense. You're using $(x,y)$ as dummy variables of integration, which you cannot do. You must write $$v(x,y) = \int_{(a,b)}^{(x,y)} -u_t(s,t)\,ds + u_s(s,t)\,dt.$$ What is the path of integration? Do you know $u$ is harmonic? That would make the integral (locally) path independent.

Comment: Yes, $u$ is harmonic, sorry! Will make the suggested changes. Thanks!